# Link 3 or more tables together in PHP MYSQLI to create wall feed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, relationship

ive been trying to link these 5 tables together because i am creating a  wall feed where posts are gotten from a user and their friend. However i am finding it difficult to select all data from these 5 tables without having mysqli having an error. This is how the database looks like.

I have a **POSTS TABLES**
[image: This is the posts table, in it it specifies the post id, user id and the type of posts: image, video, or story] 
I Also have a **USERS TABLE**
[image: The users information is stored here]
Along with the **FRIENDS TABLE**
[image]

Now depending on the post type: i have a photos table, as such
[image: The photos table has the post id, user id and other information]

The problem is how do i link all these tables together and output them as rows for a wall feed. Please i've been racking my brain

Comment: what did you try? what was the error?

Comment: Probably a `JOIN` not really a `mysqli`, nor `PHP` quesiton

Comment: I think jacob has schizophrenia.

Comment: side note, friends table should not have names, just id's

Comment: thanks for all the contributions, lmao at the jacob joke. anytime i try to join the tables it will either create duplicate fields or database errors

Comment: i was wondering though if there was a way i could use a public function as query each of the types

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p.post_category, p.post_content, u.username
FROM post_table as p, user_table as u, friends_table as f
WHERE u.user_id = p.user_id and (f.user1 = p.user_id or f.user2 = p.user_id)
```

This is just a simple way how to get data from related table.

Comment: thanks, but the problem now is how do i relate this with the other tables photos, videos and images which are specified as types in the posts table

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the current user's posts with their friends' posts into a single stream with several `left outer joins`:

```
select
    posts.*,
    users.*,
    photos.photo_source
from posts
join users
    on (users.user_id = posts.user_id)
left join friends
    on (friends.user1 = ? and friends.user2 = posts.user_id)
left join photos
    on (photos.post_id = posts.id)
where
    posts.user_id = ? or not isnull(friends.user2)
```

(Change ? to the user's ID.)

You'd be retrieving the posts where the `user_id` matches the current user or one of his friends (`friends.user2`). The `photos` table would also be selected with a `left outer join`.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i wanted to include the videos and the stories table aswell

Comment: You can add `left join videos on (videos.post_id = posts.id)` and similar for any additional optional tables.

Comment: sorry but the query brought out no result

Comment: yes, i tired it and it's not bringing out any data relating to the user or his friends, just an empty row

Comment: i tired it, but the only way it works is if i remove the last where not isnull(users.user_id) or not isnull(friends.user2) but that just outputs everything

Comment: that's what iv'e been trying to inspect since, but they kind of look the same. i'm shocked. i am using localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: my guess is the friends system, i think it only outputs from 1 side of the user

Comment: putting in your code only gets the data from user 2 and not both of the users

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: So you want to grab the friends' user details as well in addition to the post content. You can do that by joining against the users table and selecting the desired columns. See the edit above.